# Is there a different to install dplyr on rstudio because the because my r version 3.3.3 does not enable me to install it?

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]

I am trying to install dplyr, but my version of R is 3.3.3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are strongly encouraged to include information as text (i.e., as cut-and-pasted text from the console), rather than as a screenshot, wherever possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Answer (score 1):

dplyr is available for R version 3.4.0 or newer (see here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html).

R 3.3.3, which you are using, is quite old. The newest version is R 4.2.2. I heavily advise to at least update t R 4.1.0. But in order to use dyplr, you got to have at least R 3.4.0.

Comment: Alternatively, they could install an older version of dplyr from here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/ But yes, the optimal solution is simply to update R.